# spark1.3 can not read data from HDFS1

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I'm using Spark1.3.1 trying to read data from HDFS as:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val lines = sc.textFile("hdfs://192.168.0.104:9000/cur/part-r-02554")
```

I met the following excepton:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: 
com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message end-group
tag did not match expected tag.; Host Details : local host is: 
"hadoop104/192.1168.1.104"; destination host is: "hadoop104":9000;
```

Comment: I had this Exception thrown when my fs.defaultFS NameNode port in core-site.xml was different from my HDFS cluster. Hostname and port were included in the value field

Answer (score 1):

Try looking for property `fs.defaultFS` or `fs.default.name` in your `core-site.xml`. Check if `192.168.0.104` is configured as `value`, and not a `hostname`.

If a hostname is configured as a `value`, this is bound to give you an error - as this is very strictly followed. Either, use whatever is configured in `core-site.xml` or do not use an IP/hostname and just go ahead with `hdfs:/cur/part-r-02554`

Comment: I tried what you said. but it still got same error. I think it's because the version issue. I was trying to connect old hdfs1 version.

Comment: @Harman, This helped me solve a related issue of how to communicate with HDFS from an edge node without explicitly using the Hadoop client

Comment: @BrianVanover I am glad, I was of help :)